# TypeScript - Function with a red line underneath

Tags: typescript

[image]

Does anybody why the function here has a red line. When I mouse hover it it says
*

> [ts] Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property
>   was expected.

*

Comment: You are declaring a method...just do the same as getPickSet. If those definitions are placed inside an object literal you must also use a comma.

Comment: @betadeveloper Thanks, that solved part of the problem. How do I return an array from that function to the calling function.  function generatePicks(pick: string, region: string): any[] {} This is the definition I have now, it doesn't return the result as expected.